# Java - Spring MVC - Automatically populate object from form submission?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC in the controller I can just have an object from my model be a parameter in one of my methods, and a form submission that gets handled by that method would automatically populate the object.

eg:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(User u){...}
```

The user object will automatically be populated for be from the form submission.

Is there a way to have this automatically happen using Spring MVC, and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring MVC (with Spring MVC 2.5+ annotation-based configuration) it looks exactly the same way:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView edit(User u) { ... }
```

The `User` object will be automatically populated. You may also explicitly specify the name of the corresponding model attribute with `@ModelAttribute` annotation (by default attribute name is a argument's class name with first letter decapitalized, i.e. "user")

```
... (@ModelAttrbiute("u") User u) ...
```

Comment: I was looking through the petcare sample project for Spring 3.0.  In their sample they have a separate object called `UserForm` as the method parameter.  Do you know why they separate it like this?

Comment: @Spines : It may be useful when structure of your form object is different from your data model objects

Answer (score 1):

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/portlet/mvc/SimpleFormController.html#onSubmitAction(java.lang.Object)

Create a Form Controller, for example PriceIncreaseFormController and make it extend SimpleFormController

override the method `public ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command)` 
there are many variants of the above. look for the right method that suits your need. For simple flow the above method should be sufficient.

Inside the method, you can typecast command and get your Command class.

```
commandObj = ((PriceIncrease) command)
```

commandObj will have the parameters populated by spring.

in your springapp-servlet.xml you should tell spring about the PriceIncrease command class as follows and also you should have a POJO for your command class created.

```
<bean name="/priceincrease.htm" class="springapp.web.PriceIncreaseFormController">
    <property name="commandClass" value="springapp.service.PriceIncrease"/>
```

....

Answer (score 0):

In Servlets no, but in Spring MVC absolutely. Take a look at the [web framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/mvc.html) docs.

Specifically [Section 13.11.4](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments), 9th bullet point.

Comment: How do I do it in Spring MVC? I've been just using stuff like `@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("age") String age`, then manually populating the `User` object.